# Truth value of a Dataframe is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, seaborn, python-3.9

I've tried to do pairplot by seaborn with [my csv data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mb3zVJhlM643-j7T7pVrVH5vnHWTxTdo/view?usp=sharing) (this link) by follow code according to [seaborn site](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

freq_data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\frequency.csv')

freq = sns.load_dataset(freq_data)
df = sns.pairplot(iris, hue="condition", height=2.5)
plt.show()
```

the results show the trackback of ambiguous of dataframe

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\.vscode\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    freq = sns.load_dataset(freq_data)
  File "\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 485, in load_dataset
    if name not in get_dataset_names():
  File "\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1441, in __nonzero__   
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I've checked my data and result it here

```
        condition    area  sphericity  aspect_ratio
0      20 kHz   0.249       0.287         1.376
1      20 kHz   0.954       0.721         1.421
2      20 kHz   0.118       0.260         1.409
3      20 kHz   0.540       0.552         1.526
4      20 kHz   0.448       0.465         1.160
..        ...     ...         ...           ...
310    30 kHz   6.056       0.955         2.029
311    30 kHz   4.115       1.097         1.398
312    30 kHz  11.055       1.816         1.838
313    30 kHz   4.360       1.183         1.162
314    30 kHz  10.596       0.940         1.715

[315 rows x 4 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 315 entries, 0 to 314
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------        --------------  -----  
 0   condition     315 non-null    object 
 1   area          315 non-null    float64
 2   sphericity    315 non-null    float64
 3   aspect_ratio  315 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 10.0+ KB
```

I have no ideas what happen with my dataframe :(
Please advice me to solve these problem

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of [seaborn.load_dataset()](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.load_dataset.html) is name of the dataset (`{name}.csv` on https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data) not a [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) object. The return value of `seaborn.load_dataset()` is just `pandas.DataFrame`, so you don't need to do

```py
freq = sns.load_dataset(freq_data)
```

Moreover, you may want `freq_data` rather than `iris` in `df = sns.pairplot(iris, hue="condition", height=2.5)`.

Here is the final example code

```py
from io import StringIO
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = StringIO("""condition;area;sphericity;aspect_ratio
20 kHz;0.249;0.287;1.376
20 kHz;0.954;0.721;1.421
20 kHz;0.118;0.260;1.409
20 kHz;0.540;0.552;1.526
20 kHz;0.448;0.465;1.160
30 kHz;6.056;0.955;2.029
30 kHz;4.115;1.097;1.398
30 kHz;11.055;1.816;1.838
30 kHz;4.360;1.183;1.162
30 kHz;10.596;0.940;1.715
    """)

freq_data = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")

sns.pairplot(freq_data, hue="condition", height=2.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it's work for me, it can show the graph :)
But i tested with my all data and i got blank plotting :(

Comment: @SoponUdomphon I send request to get permission of your [csv data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mb3zVJhlM643-j7T7pVrVH5vnHWTxTdo/view?usp=sharing). Could you have a look at it?

Comment: @SoponUdomphon It [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mck8I.png) with me. Could you post your code to [Ubuntu Pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) with proper expiration date?

Comment: Of course https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/kx6tNQjkVH/ 
PS. I used Python 3.9.2 64-bit in VS Is it related with my problem?

Comment: @SoponUdomphon Your separator is wrong. BTW,  I use `StringIO` to build a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you don't need do that.  `freq_data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\frequency.csv')` is enough.